# how to avoid "scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme"

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I wanted to follow the link in the xpath expression i have written, but I am getting this error message. How to avoid it and successfully follow the link.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class JobSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'job'
    allowed_domains = ['www.irishjobs.ie']
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"

    #start_urls = ['http://www.irishjobs.ie/ShowResults.aspx?Keywords=python+&autosuggestEndpoint=%2Fautosuggest&Location=0&Category=&Recruiter=Company&Recruiter=Agency&btnSubmit=Search/']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url = "'http://www.irishjobs.ie/ShowResults.aspx?Keywords=python+&autosuggestEndpoint=%2Fautosuggest&Location=0&Category=&Recruiter=Company&Recruiter=Agency&btnSubmit=Search/", headers= {
            'User-Agent': self.user_agent
        })
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths= "//div[@class='job-result-title']/h2/a"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple typo in your code.
try this.

```
def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url = "http://www.irishjobs.ie/ShowResults.aspx?Keywords=python+&autosuggestEndpoint=%2Fautosuggest&Location=0&Category=&Recruiter=Company&Recruiter=Agency&btnSubmit=Search/", headers= {
            'User-Agent': self.user_agent
        })
```

there is extra `'` quote in url, remove that extra `'`. Then spider is ok.

```
yield scrapy.Request(url = "'http://www.irishjobs.ie/ShowResults.aspx?
                            ^^^
Keywords=python+&autosuggestEndpoint=%2Fautosuggest&Location=0&Category=&Recruiter=Company&Recruiter=Agency&btnSubmit=Search/"
```